# Convert binary data read from a file to an uint32 array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, type-conversion

I have a binary file that when read by python creates an array of uint8 data. How can I use numpy (or any method) to convert it to an array of uint32? Currently im building the uin32 array by reading 4 consecutive uint8 data locations and using shifts and ors to make a uin32, but it seems sloppy.

Comment: Have you considered using `struct`?

Comment: How are you reading this file?

Comment: never thought of using a struct, but its a good idea. thanks

Comment: if using `fromfile`, I think you can specify `uint32` dtype.

Answer (score 0):

Does `numpy.ndarray.view` solve your problem:

```
np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], dtype=np.uint8).view(np.uint32)
```